# Why can't this for loop be broken with 'break' or by exceeding limit? - Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, syntax

I've made a piece of java code that collects user data iteratively and asks a y/n question to break or continue the loop. But the code seems to branch: carrying on with the loop but also the rest of the code in sequence at the same time.

```
for(i = 0; i < alphabetLength; i++){
```

...

```
continueQuery = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Another activity? (y/n)"); 
        if ("y".equals(continueQuery)) {
          }
        else if ("n".equals(continueQuery)){
            //i = i + 30; 
            //break;
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please elaborate and provide a [mcve].

Comment: The only way for the code to continue the loop if the elseif conditional evaulates to ```false```. Are you entering a captial ```N```perhaps?

Comment: Sure. When I run the code with one of the loop breaking methods, the loop continues and simultaneously so does the rest of the code. I would like to know why or how to change.

Comment: No I don't believe that is the problem. I've also used just 'else' with no condition instead of 'else if', and it has given me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You're obviously not showing the whole picture here which leaves things up for speculation and assumption. That's a real poor way to ask a question, but never the less I'll give this a poke.

Using a **Input Dialog** is a strange option to use for simply asking the User if he or she wants to utilize yet another Activity. Have you considered what is to happen if the User simply closes the Input Dialog which forces it to return **null**. By merely closing the Input Dialog it should be considered as the same as entering **"n"** ...... or should it? What if the User enters anything other than "y" or "n" like maybe just a whitespace. What is to happen then? There's a lot of things that need to be taken into consideration here and....more (unnecessary) code.

I think what you are looking for is the [**continue**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_continue_statement.htm) keyword which in a **for** loop causes the loop to skip all loop code after the statement call and immediately jump to the next iteration of that loop:

```
for (int i = 0); i < alphabetLength; i++) {
    ..............................            
    ..............................            
    String continueQuery = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Another activity? (y/n)"); 
    if ("y".equals(continueQuery)) { 
        continue; 
    }
    else if ("n".equals(continueQuery) || continueQuery == null){
        break;
    } 
    ..............................            
    ..............................           
}
```

Notice how I've also added a condition within the **else if** should the User simply close the Input Dialog window. Oh, and if you want the flow to break out of the **for** loop when **"n"** is supplied then simply un-comment the **break** statement.

Of course, if the call to the Input Dialog is the last code within your **for** loop then you wont need the **continue** statement, you wont need to check for "y" at all since the the next iteration is automatically going to happen anyways. You would just need:

```
if ("n".equals(continueQuery) || continueQuery == null){
            break;
}
```

As I said earlier, using an **Input Dialog** is a strange option to use for this sort of prompt since the User is only required to enter either **"y"** or **"n"** for **Yes** or **No**. A better option would be to use a simple [**Confirm Dialog**](https://www.mkyong.com/swing/java-swing-how-to-make-a-confirmation-dialog/) instead where as the User has the option to select either a **Yes**, **No**, and perhaps the **Cancel** button if you like, something like this:

```
for (int i = 0); i < alphabetLength; i++) {
    ..............................            
    ..............................            
    int userOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like another Activity?", 
            "Another Activity?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if (userOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) { 
        continue;
    }
    else if (userOption == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) { 
        break;
    }
    ..............................            
    ..............................           
}
```